# Compile gcrypt for Vala

Tags: c, gcc, vala, libgcrypt

I'm try to compile a code write in Vala using a .vapi of libgcrypt.
I installed the library in the system and i run a test in c. The code write in C compiles without errors:
I typed the following command to compile the C code:

```
gcc -o main main.c -l gcrypt
```

The code runs perfectly.

But, the following code write in Vala don't compile using the command:

```
valac --pkg gcrypt --Xcc=-lgcrypt main.vala
```

The main.vala is

```
using GCrypt;
    public static int main(string[] args)
    {
        Hash h;
        Hash.open(out h, Hash.Algorithm.MD5, Hash.Flag.SECURE);
        return 0;
    }
```

I don't know what i doing wrong.

EDITED:
Sorry for not post the error, but there is:

`Loaded package /usr/share/vala-0.30/vapi/glib-2.0.vapi'`

`Loaded package /usr/share/vala-0.30/vapi/gobject-2.0.vapi'`

`Loaded package /usr/share/vala-0.30/vapi/gcrypt.vapi'`

`cc -o '/home/kyul/Documents/Codes/Vala/test_gcrypt/main' '/home/kyul/Documents/Codes/Vala/test_gcrypt/main.vala.c' -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 '-lgcrypt'
/home/kyul/Documents/Codes/Vala/test_gcrypt/main.vala.c: In function ‘_vala_main’:`

`/home/kyul/Documents/Codes/Vala/test_gcrypt/main.vala.c:22:38: error: ‘GCRY_MD_FLAGSECURE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  gcry_md_open (&_tmp0_, GCRY_MD_MD5, GCRY_MD_FLAGSECURE);
                                      ^
/home/kyul/Documents/Codes/Vala/test_gcrypt/main.vala.c:22:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)`

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What is the error message (if any)?  You can pass -v to valac to see what is being passed to the C compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely You are missing the `.vapi` file.

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nemequ/vala-extra-vapis/master/gcrypt.vapi
$ patch < gcrypt.patch
$ valac --vapidir=. --pkg gcrypt --Xcc=-lgcrypt main.vala
$ ./main
$ echo $?
0
```

I've never used gcrypt api from vala before and had to patch `gcrypt.vapi` for Your example to work, but the patch is trivial:

```
--- gcrypt.vapi
+++ gcrypt.vapi
@@ -619,7 +619,7 @@
            public Error get_oid (uchar[] buffer);
        }

-       [CCode (cname = "enum gcry_md_flags", cprefix = "GCRY_MD_FLAG")]
+       [CCode (cname = "enum gcry_md_flags", cprefix = "GCRY_MD_FLAG_")]
        public enum Flag {
            SECURE,
            HMAC
```

**Update:** concerning Your cipher errors, obviously the `Cipher` class is missing `free_function` mapping:

```
--- a/gcrypt.vapi   2016-02-22 21:40:34.458977385 +0200
+++ b/gcrypt.vapi   2016-02-22 21:39:59.662976449 +0200
@@ -560,7 +560,7 @@
            CBC_MAC   /* Enable CBC message auth. code (MAC). */
        }
        [Compact]
-       [CCode (cname = "gcry_cipher_hd_t", lower_case_cprefix = "gcry_cipher_")]
+       [CCode (cname = "struct gcry_cipher_handle", lower_case_cprefix = "gcry_cipher_", free_function = "gcry_cipher_close")]
        public class Cipher {
            public static Error open (out Cipher cipher, Algorithm algo, Mode mode, Flag flags);
            public void close ();
```

Comment: There it's.
Your patch don't work, but i edited manually the .vapi file and compiles e executes succesful.
But now, when a i try to compile the following code:
`using GCrypt.Cipher;
public static int main(string[] args)
{
    Cipher c;
    Cipher.open(out c, Algorithm.AES, Mode.NONE, Flag.secure);
    return 0;
}`

i get the following error: 
undefined reference to 'gcry_cipher_free'

Comment: Thanks alot. :)
I wondered if there is a function called gcry_free function in the original library
By the way, we have to update this .vapi.

Comment: @Kyul: 1) AFAIU `gcry_cipher_close` does the context clean-up. See the [docs](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Working-with-cipher-handles.html). 2) AFAIU You could make a pull request [here](https://github.com/nemequ/vala-extra-vapis) or use the vala bug tracker. Cheers!